# Howto attach a parameter to a link without id or class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, href

I have three links that unfortunately do not have a class or an id. Their href is static. I want to attach the same parameter to all three of them at the end of the URL, so my idea is to identify them based on their href value but I do not know how to do this.

The links look like:

```
<ul class="links primary-tabs">
   <li><a href="/user">Login</a></li>
   <li><a href="/user/register">Register</a></li>
   <li><a href="/user/password">Forgot Password</a></li>
</ul>
```

So far I have the following code where $destination is a PHP variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".page-user .primary-tabs a").attr("href", "/user/register?destination='.$destination.'");
});
```

This would, of course, change all of the three links to /user/register?destination=....

Can anyone help me out on how to attach $destination to all of the three links preserving their original href?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with a function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".page-user .primary-tabs a").attr("href", functon(i, href) {
     return href + "?destination='.$destination.'";
  });
});
```

This just appends that querystring to each, `href` being the previous value inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use each and this:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<ul class="links primary-tabs">
   <li><a href="/user">Login</a></li>
   <li><a href="/user/register">Register</a></li>
   <li><a href="/user/password">Forgot Password</a></li>
</ul>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.primary-tabs a").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr('href') + '?destination=foo');
    });
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Two things, your `<ul>` shouldn't be in the `<head>`, and `.attr()` has accepted a function since jQuery 1.1, so it's a much more efficient approach.

Comment: thx @nick craver - copy&paste error, i think its a matter of coding style not effectiveness imho

Comment: I wasn't commenting on effectiveness, I was saying it's less efficient :)  That's not a really debatable point, you can fire up performance tests to get hard data.